# Mathematical optimization in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mathematical-optimization

I have the following data frames:

```
Required <- data.table( Country=c("AT", "BE", "BG", "CY"),Mat1=c(0,5,0,5),Mat2=c(0,3,2,0),Mat3=c(10,2,0,12))
Supplied <- data.table( Country=c("AT", "BE", "BG", "CY"),Mat1=c(0,4,0,10),Mat2=c(20,20,20,0),Mat3=c(8,10,0,10))

> Required
   Country Mat1 Mat2 Mat3
1:      AT    0    0   10
2:      BE    5    3    2
3:      BG    0    2    0
4:      CY    5    0    2

> Supplied
   Country Mat1 Mat2 Mat3
1:      AT    0   20    8
2:      BE    4   20   10
3:      BG    5   20    0
4:      CY   10    0   10
```

"Required" shows the requirement of three types of materials to different countries, while "Supplied" shows the supply capacity of these countries. I seek to apply an optimization algorithm by which the "Required" data frame is modified according to the supply capacity. For instance, 5 units of "Mat1" are required to the country "BE", while it can only supply 4 units. The algorithm should look for the less constrained country to supply this material, in this case countries "BG" and "CY" both have 5 units "available". The less constrained country is thus the one that has the most units of material available in absolute terms.

The resulting requirement table "RequiredNew" should thus be:

```
> Required
       Country Mat1 Mat2 Mat3
    1:      AT    0    0    8
    2:      BE    4    3    3
    3:      BG  0.5    2    0
    4:      CY  5.5    0    3
```

Any ideas on how to proceed? This is an example and the actual table is quite bigger, so I seek a programatical approach.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So, do you want to cover as much as possible the requirements with the national supplies possibly importing from other countries ? Numbers must be integers, or can you supply for example 0.5 to one country and 0.5 to another ?

Comment: Could you refine your definition of "less constrained"? The absolute surplus of CY is 5, and the absolute surplus of BG is also 5. The percent surplus of CY is 50%, and the percent surplus of BG is 100%. So why aren't you choosing BG is the country to supply the material?

Comment: @digEmAll Numbers can be decimals, I have corrected my example to fix a mistake and to show this possibility.

Comment: @rbatt I have corrected my example, now 0.5 units are required from both BG and CY, since both have 5 units "available".

Comment: Mmh, I don't really understand... why BG final requirement is 0.5 for Mat1, if since the beginning it needs zero of Mat1 ? Also, considering Mat3, I don't understand the final values of 3 for both BE and CY...I would have expected 2 ...

Comment: @digEmAll Let's say you need 10 units of Mat1, and at first you want to get 5 from BE and 5 from CY. Since BE will only supply 4, you need to find the remaining 1 somewhere else. I assume that the country with higher supply capacity in absolute terms will provide you with that unit. In this case, both BG and CY have 5 units available once you have made your requirements, thus both will provided you with equal quantities, 0.5. Do I make sense now?

Comment: @David: ok, now I think I got it...

Comment: What if CY had 1 more unit available than BG; would CY provide the full additional 1 unit? Or is this an issue of being a weighted average, where we determine how many extra units are needed, then how much each other country provides depends on the % extra that they have?

Comment: @rbatt In that case CY would provide the full additional unit, since it will have a supply capacity of 6 versus 5 of BG. I assume the less constrained country is measured in absolute terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit convoluted, but it should work:

```
library(data.table)

Required <- data.table( Country=c("AT", "BE", "BG", "CY"),Mat1=c(0,5,0,5),Mat2=c(0,3,2,0),Mat3=c(10,2,0,2))
Supplied <- data.table( Country=c("AT", "BE", "BG", "CY"),Mat1=c(0,4,5,10),Mat2=c(20,20,20,0),Mat3=c(8,10,0,10))

# I prefer to work with matrices, so here I turn Required and Supplied into matrices
req <- as.matrix(Required[,-1,with=FALSE])
row.names(req) <- Required$Country
sup <- as.matrix(Supplied[,-1,with=FALSE])
row.names(sup) <- Supplied$Country

# create a copy of Required data.table to contain the result (we'll overwrite the values)
RequiredNew <- copy(Required)

# for each material...
for(col in 1:(ncol(req))){

  # for each country we compute the remaining stock and requirement after satisfying itself
  netreq <- req[,col] - sup[,col]
  netreq[netreq < 0] <- 0
  netstk <- sup[,col] - req[,col]
  netstk[netstk < 0] <- 0

  # we loop until we satisfy all the requirements or we finish the stock
  finalreq <- req[,col] - netreq
  while(sum(netreq) > 0 && sum(netstk) > 0){
    maxavailidxs <- which(netstk == max(netstk))
    requiredqty <- min(sum(netreq),sum(netstk[maxavailidxs]))
    deltareq <- (requiredqty * netreq) / sum(netreq)
    deltastk <- rep(0,length(netstk))
    deltastk[maxavailidxs] <- requiredqty / length(netstk[maxavailidxs])

    netreq <- netreq - deltareq
    netstk <- netstk - deltastk

    finalreq <- finalreq + deltastk
  }

  # we set the current material final requirement column into the result data.table
  set(RequiredNew,NULL,col+1L, finalreq)
}

RequiredNew
> RequiredNew
   Country Mat1 Mat2 Mat3
1:      AT  0.0    0    8
2:      BE  4.0    3    3
3:      BG  0.5    2    0
4:      CY  5.5    0    3
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works as intended. However, I realised I oversimplified the example and now I cannot implement it to my real data because of my limited knowledge in R. Specifically, every country delivers multiple products, so that "maxavailidxs" should look for a specific product instead of the whole column. I have created a new post with a better example here, since this is on hold: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938512/conditional-mathematical-optimization-in-r. I hope you can help me with your code without too many modifications. Thank you again!