# Conditional mathematical optimization in R

Tags: r, data.table, mathematical-optimization

I have the following data frames:

```
Required <- data.table( Country=c("AT Iron", "AT Energy", "BE Iron", "BE Energy", "BG Iron", "BG Energy"),Prod1=c(5,10,0,5,0,5),Prod2=c(25,5,10,0,0,5))
Supplied <- data.table( Country=c("AT Iron", "AT Energy", "BE Iron", "BE Energy", "BG Iron", "BG Energy"),Prod1=c(10,5,5,10,5,10),Prod2=c(20,20,20,0,15,10))


> Required
     Country Prod1 Prod2
1:   AT Iron     5    25
2: AT Energy    10     5
3:   BE Iron     0    10
4: BE Energy     5     0
5:   BG Iron     0     0
6: BG Energy     5     5

> Supplied
     Country Prod1 Prod2
1:   AT Iron    10    20
2: AT Energy     5    20
3:   BE Iron     5    20
4: BE Energy    10     0
5:   BG Iron     5    15
6: BG Energy    10    10
```

"Required" shows the initial material and energy requirements to manufacture two products, and the materials and energy are supplied by three different countries. For example, product 1 would require, for Energy, 10 units from AT, 5 units from BE and 5 units from BG. "Supplied" shows the actual supply capacity of the countries. Following the example, AT cannot supply 10 units of energy but 5 units, so another country must supply the remaining units. I assume that the country with the most net supply capacity (that is, once discounted the initial requirement) will provide the remaining units. In this case, both BE and BG have 5 units of net supply capacity, so both will provide with equal units, 2.5.

I seek an optimization algorithm that creates a new "Required" table, "RequiredNew", considering supply constrains and the above mentioned assumption. The resulting table should look like:

```
> RequiredNew
     Country Prod1 Prod2
1:   AT Iron     5    20
2: AT Energy    10     5
3:   BE Iron     0    10
4: BE Energy   7.5     0
5:   BG Iron     0     5
6: BG Energy   7.5     5
```

In the link below I posted a similar question which was solved by user digEmAll, so a similar approach would be suitable. However, I rephrased the question so that it becomes clearer and resembles more to my actual data.

[Mathematical optimization in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923107/mathematical-optimization-in-r/31925479#31925479)

I apologise by the multiple posts. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is this not a duplicate? What is different in your question from the one that was put on hold? Why is the answer given there not working here? Have you tried adapting the answer to your older question to this one here? And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: It's been 2 hours and I have not achieved to implement the answer to my real data...I am not that great with R unfortunately.

Comment: Couldn't you simply split energy and iron requirements and supplies on multiple columns, e.g. `Prod1.Iron` and `Prod2.Energy` and solve using the given algorithm ?

Comment: @digEmAll Yes, I think that is doable. I was thinking of a more straightforward solution but that works as well. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @David: or, similarly, you could run the algorithm once by passing the data.table filtered by "Iron", then run the algorithm again by passing the data.table filtered by "energy" and finally merge the two results...

Comment: @digEmAll Yes, but the problem is that I have 163 requirement categories, so it is not very practical...

Comment: I see, well IMO the split-by-column approach is absolutely feasible

Comment: @digEmAll Any tip about how can the table be re-shaped? So far I have not made it...

Comment: I think I answered myself in my comment...'reshape' function of course...

Comment: Yes, I think there's something more specific for data.table, `dcast.data.table` function. Anyway, to do this I think you should first split Contry column into two columns, one for the country and one for the required element (iron, energy...)